# Unable to locate package mssql-server

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to install MSSQL @ Ubuntu 16.04 (as recommended @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-linux-2017)

But that's the error I'm currently facing `E: Unable to locate package mssql-server`

```
test@test-VirtualBox:~$ wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
OK

test@test-VirtualBox:~$ sudo add-apt-repository "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list)" 

test@test-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease            
Hit:3 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease          
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017 xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done

test@test-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mssql-server
```

`What I'm doing wrong?`

I've been trying many various Google queries like `unable to locate package *mssql-server* site:github.com` but nothing really solves my problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know whether the Ubuntu install in your virtual machine is 32-bit or 64-bit? The mssql-server packages are 64-bit only, and will be ignored on 32-bit install.

Comment: @JasonMusgrove Well, it worked :) Write your comment as an answer , so I'll be able to accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to check whether the Ubuntu installed in your virtual machine is 32-bit or 64-bit. The packages for `mssql-server` are 64-bit only, and will be ignored on a 32-bit install.

Answer (score 0):

check whether the Ubuntu installed in your virtual machine is 32-bit or 64-bit or ARM The packages for mssql-server are 64-bit only and it wont works with any ARM or 32 bit